# Where are the demo template files stored after installing them?

Tags: solspace, add-on, solspace-user

I am using the solspace user addon to handle webfacing member login stuff. The installation guide says to install the demo templates in order to see how the addon works. So i install them and they are displayed nicely when i click the link that is provided after i clicked the install demo template button.

How do i get to these files that are being generated? I would like to change where they are located on my server as well as style them differently to match my website. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo templates are stored in the database along with your other EE templates. You can view them by going to your EE Template Manager and look for the template groups called **user_main**, **user_inc**, etc (unless you prefixed them differently).

The assets (CSS, JS, images) for the demo templates are located in the themes folder, at **/themes/user/user/code_pack/**

The demo templates are meant to be a starting point for using the add-on (in this case, User) on your site. You can copy, paste and modify code chunks out of those templates into other templates, or you can use them mostly as is and then adjust them to however you please. If you plan on using the demo templates as they come installed, I recommend that you place your any new CSS file elsewhere on your site though, and updating future versions of User may tell you to overwrite the files located at **/themes/user/user/**

And just to clarify, the demo templates are just regular templates, and just examples of the add-on at work. You can adjust them or not use them at all if you wish. :)